# Brackets 1.9 font style and font size changing

Tags: brackets

Updated my Brackets to v.1.9 and can`t correctly change font style. (Windows 8.1 x64)

- When write font family and apply size dropped to 12px;
- When change size, font dropped to default family;

Editing defaultPreferences.json and brackets.json not resolve the problem.

Comment: A user ([Prasad](http://stackoverflow.com/users/7188693/prasad)) without the reputation to comment posted [this github link](https://github.com/adobe/brackets/issues/13205) that affirms several people are experiencing a similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

It has been recently fixed in Brackets 1.10 pre-release build, so you don't need to do any extra hacks. You can find the downloads here: https://github.com/adobe/brackets/releases/tag/release-1.10-prerelease-1